# Creating custom windows in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to customize our installer which is based on NSIS. My question is could we create custom windows? Where I mean not customizing Modern UI or other built-in surface, but building a totally new look with custom Window header, buttons and other elements like list where all element have other state, and all of the states are represented with an animated item before the text.

So I want to develop my look from ground to the peak. This can be done somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a resource hacker of your choice, e.g. [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm), [XNResourceEditor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm), [Resource Hacker FX](http://rammichael.com/resource-hacker-fx) or good old [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). You'll have to make sure to use the same IDs for the controls, so you probably best start by editing on of the existing UIs.

Answer (score 0):

Like idleberg said you have to edit one of the .exe resource files (in the Contrib folder) with a resource editor. To apply the new UI you have to use the `ChangeUI` instruction. You can change all pages or just a single page...